# Changing values in a list of lists effectively

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list that looks like this:

```
[['B Borg', '3', '3', '1.0'], ['F Perry', '7', '8', '0.875'], ['R Nadal', '3', '5', '0.6']]
```

I want the user to choose 2 of these tennis players to play a simulated tennis match where the winner is chosen randomly. So if I choose B Borg and F Perry to encounter each other, B Borg randomly wins. The end result should look like this:

```
[['B Borg', '4', '4', '1.0'], ['F Perry', '7', '9', '0.875'], ['R Nadal', '3', '5', '0.6']]
```

The 1st element in the list is the name, 2nd is the matches won, 3rd is total played games and 4th is the win percentage.

Is there any 'neat' way to do it? I've tried using multiple if-elif-else blocks. sure it works but its a lot of text.

Comment: Can you show those if-elif-else blocks you speak of?

Comment: It might be a good time to learn about classes

Comment: Your data structure should at the least be a dictionary (possibily an object) and the win-percentage should not be stored only computed. Its a cheap operation, and it might get out of sync with the actual data.

Answer (score 3):

Use classes!!

```
class TennisPlayer(object):
    def __init__(self,name,wins=0,games_played=0,win_pct=None):
        self.name = name
        self.wins = wins
        self.games_played = games_played

        # Note that although I do take win_pct as a parameter, I never use
        # it anywhere. This trick may be useful for you if you end up maintaining
        # code someone else has written and don't need part of their data
        # structure anymore, but don't feel like refactoring code is worth the time

    @property
    def win_pct(self):
        return self.wins/self.games_played

    # as per lanzz, the @property token basically makes this a function that can
    # be called like an instance variable.
    #
    # >>> player = TennisPlayer("Foo Bar",2,3) # 2 wins 1 loss
    # >>> player.win_pct
    # 0.6666666666666666
    #
    # You could probably make this prettier using string formatting.
    # Something like return "{:.2f}%".format(self.wins/self.games_played*100)
    # but it will make data manipulation much harder. Consider writing
    # a TennisPlayer.print_stats() function that will just pretty print
    # all the stats to stdout

    def win_game(self,other):
        self.games_played += 1
        self.wins += 1
        other.games_played +=1

lst = [['B Borg', '3', '3', '1.0'], ['F Perry', '7', '8', '0.875'], ['R Nadal', '3', '5', '0.6']]

tennisplayers = [TennisPlayer(*player) for player in lst]

# randomly choose B Borg (tennisplayers[0]) and F Perry (tennisplayers[1])

tennisplayers[0].win_game(tennisplayers[1])
```

There are as many implementations of this as you could possibly imagine. The best of which (to my mind, in any case) would be to also implement a `TennisMatch` class as such:

```
class TennisMatch(object):
    def __init__(self,player1,player2):
        if type(player1) == list:
            # implement special handlers for doubles games
        else:
            self.player1 = player1
            self.player2 = player2

    def play_match(self):
        # do some stuff here
        # to determine who wins and
        # who goes crying to mommy
        for player in [player1,player2]:
            if player == winner: player.wins += 1
            player.games_played += 1
```

Then you can ignore the `def win_game` I put in the `TennisPlayer` class, as it's really just a poorly implemented setter. This works much better.

Comment: `TennisPlayer.win_pct` should be a method or a `@property`.

Comment: I'll admit my understanding of `@property` is about the same as my understanding of Quantum Mechanics. Can you link me somewhere cool?

Answer (score 2):

Another solution with classes (basically the same as adsmith's, but I was already typing it, so oh well.)

```
import random

class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.wins = 0
        self.games = 0
    def win(self):
        self.wins += 1
        self.games += 1
    def lose(self):
        self.games += 1
    def __str__(self):
        win_pct = self.wins/self.games
        return '{:10} {:10} {:10} {:10.2}'.format(self.name, self.wins, self.games, win_pct)

def play_game(p1, p2):
    winner, loser = random.sample([p1, p2], 2)
    winner.win()
    loser.lose()

players = [Player(name) for name in ['B Borg', 'F Perry', 'R Nadal']]

for _ in range(20):
    play_game(*random.sample(players, 2))
for player in players:
    print(player)
```

Example result:

```
B Borg              7         15       0.47
F Perry             7         14        0.5
R Nadal             6         11       0.55
```